# Google Test and std::vector range exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, vector, googletest

I test my C++ code with googletest. When a `vector::_M_range_check` exception is thrown because a `std::vector` is accessed with a wrong index, googletest reports:

```
C++ exception with description "vector::_M_range_check" thrown in the test body.
```

Great, now I'd also like to know which vector, which index and which range. How can I easily get this information, keeping the test code in googletest unit test cases?

(I almost begin long for Java with its good old [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)...)

Comment: --gtest_catch_exceptions=0

Comment: @JaredC this flag terminates the tests after an exception is thrown, but the output gives no more information about the origin of the exception (vector, index, range)

Comment: @cls: If you run the test in a debugger, or examine the core dump after termination, then you should see where the unhandled exception was thrown from. Alternatively, you could put a breakpoint on `std::__throw_out_of_range`, which is the function the GNU library calls to throw the exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run with this command line option then your exception will bubble all the way out:

```
--gtest_catch_exceptions=0
```

Doing this inside of a debugger will give you the exact stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Right, but not the index and the bounds as the cause of the error.

Comment: @cls That information is readily available once the debugger has stopped.

Answer (score 7):

Google Test isn't involved here.  Your C++ Standard Library implementation is throwing an exception, and it's up to your C++ Standard Library implementation to decide how verbose to make its exceptions.

Since you're getting an exception, I assume that you're using `std::vector::at` instead of `std::vector::operator[]`.  There are a couple of possible approaches you could take to getting more information.

First, you could replace calls to `at` with calls to `operator[]` (personally, I don't find `at`'s exception-throwing range checking to be very useful, and it does have a performance overhead) and use your C++ Standard Library implementation's iterator debugging.  For example, with g++, if I use `operator[]` and compile with `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG` to turn on range checking for `operator[]`, I get an error similar to the following:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.3/debug/vector:237:error: attempt to subscript container
    with out-of-bounds index 0, but container only holds 0 elements.
```

Second, you could replace calls to `at` with calls to `test_at` or similar: (untested)

```
template <typename T>
T& test_at(std::vector<T>& v, size_t n) {
    // Use Google Test to display details on out of bounds.
    // We can stream additional information here if we like.
    EXPECT_LT(n, v.size()) << "for vector at address " << &v;

    // Fall back to at, and let it throw its exception, so that our
    // test will terminate as expected.
    return v.at(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vector::at(size_type n)` is documented as throwing `out_of_range` on invalid `n` (23.2.3p17).  `out_of_range` does not carry information on the container or index, so you'll have to wrap `at` if you want that information:

```
template<typename T> struct my_vector: public std::vector<T> {
  using std::vector<T>;
  struct at_out_of_range: public std::out_of_range {
    my_vector *vector;
    size_type size;
    size_type n;
    at_out_of_range(my_vector *vector, size_type size, size_type n):
      std::out_of_range("at_out_of_range"), vector(vector), size(size), n(n) {}
  };
  reference at(size_type n) {
    try {
      return std::vector<T>::at(n);
    } catch(std::out_of_range &ex) {
      std::throw_with_nested(at_out_of_range(this, size(), n));
    }
  }
};
```

Note that `at` is not virtual, so you must call through the wrapped `at` to get the nested exception.